# Kafka-node suddenly consumes from offset 0

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, node-kafka

Sometimes, kafka-node consumer starts consuming from offset 0, while its default behavior it to consume only newer messages. Then it will not switch back to its default behavior. Do you know how to solve this and what happens and its behavior suddenly changes? The code is very simple and this happens without altering the code.

```
var kafka = require("kafka-node") ;
  Consumer = kafka.Consumer;
  client = new kafka.KafkaClient();


  consumer = new Consumer(client, [{ topic: "Topic_23", partition: 0}
                                    ]);


consumer.on("message", function(message) {

    console.log(message)


  });
```

The only solution I have found so far is to change the kafka topic. Then everything works fine again. Any ideas ?

Comment: Can you share the options for your Kafka Consumer?

Comment: Giorgo, there are none. Only the default settings as I have presented them.

Answer (score 1):

In Kafka, offsets are not associated to specific consumers but instead, they  are linked to the *Consumer Groups*. In your code, you don't provide the Consumer Group therefore, every time you fire up the consumer, it is being assigned to a different Consumer Group and thus, the offset starts from `0`.

The following should do the trick (obviously the first time you are going to read all the messages):

```
var kafka = require("kafka-node") ;

Consumer = kafka.Consumer;
client = new kafka.KafkaClient();

payload = [{
    topic: "Topic_23", 
    partition: 0
}]

var options = {
    groupId: 'test-consumer-group',
    fromOffset: 'latest'
};


consumer = new Consumer(client, payload, options);
consumer.on("message", function(message) {
    console.log(message)
  });
```

Comment: I need to add [] to the payload message or it throws : TypeError: topics.some is not a function. And if I add that, then it read all the messages from the beginning again. Not altered behavior unfortunately.

Comment: Did you run it twice?

Comment: Also, can you share the output of `./bin/kafka-run-class.sh kafka.tools.GetOffsetShell --broker-list yourHost:9092 --topic Topic_23 ` please?